# What do typical transaction cost models predict about the long-term price impact of buying 1% of a stock’s shares outstanding?

Tags: transaction-costs

Assuming that the stock has 100% annual turnover, this amounts to buying 2.5 days of total volume. Of course, such a trade will take a long time to execute.

The question is: suppose the trade can be done very slowly. What kind of long-term market impact would be predicted by typical transaction cost models on Wall St?